# Where are ActiveObjects entity schema versions stored?

Tags: database, migration, jira, active-objects

I implemented ActiveObjectsUpgradeTask. Data migrated. I want to rollback this migration, but I don't know where the migration version numbers or version schema table are in ActiveObjects.
Didn't find anything in the documentation for the whole day.
Perhaps I misunderstand how structure migration works in AO. I just assume that the versions returned by the getModelVersion() method are stored somewhere.

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 1):

[How to check if update tasks ran successfully.](https://deja.pw/2016/12/22/how-to-check-if-update-tasks-ran-successful.html)

My search was successful. Based on the above article, version numbers of models in AO are stored in a table called `propertyentry`.